# How to fetch a request in laravel from ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to send multiple data to store more tha 1 row in a data base in Laravel, for that I'm using ajax as follow:

```
var postData = [];

for (i = 0 ; i<100; i++){             
    postData.push({form_name: name[i], etc...});
}

$.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: {{route(createForm)}},
    headers: {"X-CSRF-TOKEN": token},
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(postData),
});
```

When I check de console the data it's being send pretty good but I don't have any clue in how to fetch the request in the controller, when it is just a single request the controller works perfect like this:

```
public function createForm(Request $data, User $user)
{
    if ($data->ajax()){
        $form=new Form($data->all());
        $user->forms()->save($form); 
    }
}
```

But as I said, I don't know if the request is now an array or how can I handle it to store all the data in the DB with a loop

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It seems you are sending an array of objects. I see a loop in your javascript. Are you sending more than one object?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea, but i don't know in the controller how to fetch each object (request) to store all of them in the data base

Comment: the controller code that I wrote, is the one for just one object, but I would like to convert that in a loop that fetch all the objects and store all of them in the DB "in the laravel way"

Comment: In your function, do `dd($data->all());` and post the result in your question. I want to see what you send to see how to loop through it.

Comment: array:9 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "field_name" => "temp1"
    "_token" => "J5OGyGLd0qCS4oB9rQcm9ekBLwTBnlexWjSriif6"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "field_name" => "temp2"
    "_token" => "J5OGyGLd0qCS4oB9rQcm9ekBLwTBnlexWjSriif6"
  ]
  2 ... and so on...
  ]
]

Comment: Your data is an array, loop over it in createForm and add each element into the db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function createForm(Request $data, User $user)
{
    foreach( $data->all() as $row) {
        $form = new Form($row);
        $user->forms()->save($form); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was trying to loop only the variable $data, and off course didn’t' work, I guess it was a silly question after all, again thanks a lot, I couldn’t figurate that out by myself.